# WordPress : setting up wordpress on live server

Tags: php, wordpress, web-hosting

I am transferring  WordPress theme from one server to another, the other developer provided me

```
1- all the files from public_html folder 
2- exported SQL file for site to be transferred
```

now this is what I did, I did upload all the files to public_html folder in new hosting, created a new database and  assigned it a new user with all privileges and updated wp-config.php

I've to install wordpress in my server. Now confusion is that when I try to install wordpress its creating a  database and once i am installed I've 2 databases one  that I imported one that wordpress got during installation and I am not sure  which one to link with wp-config.php  please help me with it how do I manage this problem

Answer (score 1):

You should run the wordpress installer in your new live server, let it create the database, and only export the tables of your previous server's database and import it in the new.

Note that there might be entries in the database that have urls with the previous host (if both your servers have the same host it won't be an issue).

Comment: now when i try to install it gives me this error "The directory you typed already exists! Please type in another directory name." what should i remove ?

Comment: I would remove everything and do a clean install of wordpress, and then move the template files and resources to the new instalation.

Comment: so if i remove everything under public_html and then install wordpress  i will  set up cofing.php , import db theme and plugins folder thats it ?

Comment: thank you very much for your help just one point  db , theme folder and plugins is that all ? i mean  rest of the folder  are useless if i have a new installation ? i dont want to messup once again after going through process . please

Comment: You should check the uploads (images and such)

Comment: i think if i upload whole wp-cotent after installation   replacing existing one that came during installation is that okay ?

Comment: I think that would be enough, but double check everything after uploading.

Comment: ok , will check that as i've got backup against everything thank you very much for your time , will mark as accepted once it worked for me :)

Comment: No problem. glad to help and i hope everything works :)

Answer (score 1):

After you create the database, restore it from the backup of the database you have using PHPMyAdmin

Make sure the domain name on the database is correct, I think you need to change it on wp_options table (2 places)

Should work fine, if not, send me a chat message

Answer (score 0):

if you have all content from publichtml, and you have some domain as before, you do not need to reinstall it.

Import database, update the wp_config.php, copy all files from publichtml in your new document root of the webserver and you should be done.

Answer (score 0):

- Export database from current installation.
- Upload all files to `public_html` folder.
- Install wordpress.
  (During installation, keep credentials same as the previous installation).
  Once installed.
- Go to `phpmyadmin`, find newly created database.
- Select all tables, Drop all of them.
- Now import previous database.
  You're done !